# How to customize test report in nightwatch?

Tags: report, nightwatch.js

Nightwatch has xml junit report by default, but I need to customize that report and can't find how to do. For example, test report should display count of tests.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the following to generate custom reports in nightwatch using handlebars and nightwatch-html-reporter [HTML Report](https://gist.github.com/rarcega/b5088b47561c189ae891)
>
> You can will get the report of in Html.
>
> To get the count in that report you can use any of assertion methods in nightwatch then it should be in the report.

Answer (score 0):

test_runner.js is the file you would edit to customize your tests.